# Regex to remove redundant multiplication/division involving zero or one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an odd problem where I am receiving computer generated equations (as a string) where multiplications/divisions with zero or one and lone zeros are occasionally present. These equations are to be presented to a user in string form.

I know that I can remove these redundant parts of the equation by implementing a kind of parser, but I was curious as to whether a regular expression could be used to remove them.

I came up with the following before I finally gave up on my (quite limited) regex skills:

```
/([^\+\-]*(?:0|0\*|\*0){1,}[^\+\-]*)|(?:1\*|\*1)/g
```

It seems to work only if:

- there are no non-zero numbers with a zero in them (ie. no 10's,20's,etc.)
- there are no negations.

It also doesn't work well with parentheses. Unfortunately parentheses are quite common.

Note that removing the redundant portions stated above may result in redundant parentheses or "zero" parentheses (ie it could turn out like `()*x`, which is equivalent to `0*x`). The redundant parentheses are not as much of an issue, but I assume the "zero" parentheses could be removed by a second pass similar to the first looking for `()`. If either of these could be done in the same regex as the one that solves the problem I would be extremely impressed.

So I turn to you regex gurus of Stack Overflow. Can it be done?

### Assumptions

The following can be assumed true about the stringified equations:

- There are **no divisions by zero**, equations will not have any occurrence of `[expr]/0`or even expressions that evaluate to `[expr]/0` such as `[expr]/sin(0)`.
- The only operators within the equations themselves are `+` `-` `*` and `/`.
- Minus operator (`-`) includes both subtraction *and* negation, although negation is ***always*** surrounded by parentheses.
- Any operation other than the above (`sin`,`cos`, `pow`, etc.) will appear as a function call. (no `^` `%`, etc.)

### Sample Equation

```
"(0+(0/0.5+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*cos(k)+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*(-sin(k))+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*0)*x+(0+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*sin(k)+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*cos(k)+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*0)*y+(0+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*0+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*0+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*1)*z)"
```

Quite cluttered isn't it?

Comment: It would probably be a simpler / faster task from both a programmer time spent and CPU time spent perspective to simply evalulate and blow up on a div by zero. I can make most regex solution fail with something like "0 / cos(2pi) - 1". The "detect when they happen" is interesting though...

Comment: Arguably a better approach is to write an evaluator so that you have full control over when a division "fails".

Comment: Thanks for your interest @jdphenix and @Jack, but the question doesn't (or at least shouldn't) give any indication for a desire to detect divisions by zero. As stated as the first point under Assumptions, no equation will have a division by zero (I believe that includes evaluated zeros, `sin(0)`, `cos(1)`, etc.). In other words, *zero will only show up in the dividend of a division operation* `(0/x)`. Sorry if that wasn't clear...

Comment: So your question is more about _"Delete anything doesn't change the outcome of the equations"_? It's going to have to be quite a complicated algorithm just maybe uses regexes, but don't expect a sole regex to be your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After leaving the comment I couldn't resist having a crack at it :)

You're biggest problem is nested parentheses. Regexes themselves are really bad at handling nested structures. This is a prime example of my mantra *"Regular expressions are a **tool**, not a solution"*.

With regexes as your tool, you can apply kind of a "leaf-first" (or bottom-up) approach for this tree-structure, that's what I do in the first part `while (sEq.match(...)) {...}`. After that I can walk through the created `array` and do some simple text edits.

I've also added that `1*`, `*1` and `/1` are deleted as they similarly don't affect the equation. You could probably expand this to make it smart enough to replace `sin(0)`/`cos(0)` with `0` and `1` respectively, then the solution would be even smaller in some cases.

*(As mentioned in the comments of the code, this breaks if the equation contains stuff like `5.0*4` because JavaScript regexes don't have lookbehind so I'm trusting the `\b` word boundary to do that work for me. Simply adding logic that deletes unnecessary decimals would solve this though. Something like `sEq = sEq.replace(/\.0+\b/g, '');` but I don't know if that's necessary for your use-case.)* **Edit: now fixed, `5.0*4` should remain in tact**

This is not thoroughly tested though, feedback welcome.

```js
var sEq = "(0+(0/0.5+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*cos(k)+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*(-sin(k))+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*0)*x+(0+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*sin(k)+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*cos(k)+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*0)*y+(0+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*0+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*0+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*1)*z)";

var aParts = [];

document.getElementById('output').value = sEq + '\n';

while (sEq.match(/\([^()]*\)/)) {
  // while there are still "leafs", save them to aParts and replace with
  // a reference to their index in aParts, making their parent a new
  // "leaf" because it now doesn't contain the round brackets anymore
  sEq = sEq.replace(/([a-z]*)\(([^()]*)\)/gi, function(m, f, a) {
    var n = aParts.length;
    aParts[n] = {
      'found':m,
      'funct':f,
      'arith':a
    };
    return '[' + n + ']';
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < aParts.length; i++) {

  // isolate divisions/multiplications
  var dms = aParts[i]['arith'].split(/(?=[+-])/);

  for (var j = 0; j < dms.length; j++) {
    // if the isolated part is multiplied by or divided into 0, replace with 0
    if (dms[j].match(/([^.]|^)\b0[*\/]|\*0(?!\.?0*[1-9])/)) {
      dms[j] = dms[j].replace(/([+-]?).*/, '$1'+'0');
    }
    // remove /1, *1 and 1*
    dms[j] = dms[j].replace(/[\/*]1\b(?!\.0*[1-9])(?:\.0*)?/g, '').replace(/([^.]|^)\b1\*/g, '$1');
  }
  
  // join back together, remove 0+, +0 and -0; 0- results in negation
  aParts[i]['arith'] = dms.join('').replace(/[+-]0(?!\.?0*[1-9])(?:\.?0*)?/g, '').replace(/([^.]|^)\b0(?:\+|(-))/g, '$1$2');
  
  // if after this the part contains just 0, perpetuate down to further eliminate
  if (aParts[i]['funct']=='' && aParts[i]['arith']=='0') {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < aParts.length; j++) {
      if (aParts[j]['arith'].indexOf('[' + i + ']') != -1) {
        aParts[j]['arith'] = aParts[j]['arith'].replace('[' + i + ']', '0');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // add back parts previously simplified by replacing [n] with the content of aParts[n]
  aParts[i]['arith'] = aParts[i]['arith'].replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function (m, n) {
    return aParts[parseInt(n)]['funct'] + '(' + aParts[parseInt(n)]['arith'] + ')';
  });
  
  // This is just to show the progress of the algorithm
  document.getElementById('parts').value += i + '\t' + aParts[i]['found'] + '\n';
  var tmp = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < aParts.length; a++) {
    tmp[a] = {
      'funct':aParts[a]['funct'],
      'arith':aParts[a]['arith'].replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function (m, n) {
        return tmp[parseInt(n)]['funct'] + '(' + tmp[parseInt(n)]['arith'] + ')';
      })
    };
  }
  // some steps didn't change after analysing, only append when significant
  if (document.getElementById('output').value.indexOf('\n' + tmp[tmp.length-1]['arith'] + '\n') ==-1)
    document.getElementById('output').value += tmp[tmp.length-1]['arith'] + '\n';
}

document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML =
  aParts[aParts.length-1]['funct'] +
  '(' + aParts[aParts.length-1]['arith'] + ')';
```

```html
<h3>Parts isolated:</h3>
<textarea id="parts" rows="10" style="width:100%" wrap="off"></textarea>
<h3>Steps that simplified the equation:</h3>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" style="width:100%" wrap="off"></textarea>
<h3>Solution:</h3>
<pre id="solution"></pre>
```

Comment: Good deal right here, I got stuck on lack of lookbehind on this and sat my attempt down last night

Comment: @jdphenix yeah it's a deal-breaker sometimes, but I fixed it now with a little capture-group that is always placed back into the string when doing replacement. Combined with `\b` I believe this is solid.

Comment: That is pretty crazy, I bow to your far superior regex skills funkwurm. At the same time, the code is hardly readable (at least to me) even with the helpful comments. Trying to follow it hurt my head. I had already gotten through most of a recursive, non-regex approach when I saw this, so I finished it up.

Comment: By all means ask for clarification, I'm here to help. If we can take the best of both our solutions to have one with small code footprint yet still fast that'd be cool. My comments say what the code does, but not how, where is it that you lose track? To get a grip on the more complicated regexes like the one that removes `*0`, `0*`, `0/`, look at a visual explanation of [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ww-NBsu9_D7lf0qy) or a textual one of [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zK1nF9/1) (top right section). Regex101 also includes substitution that shows the deletion at the bottom half.

Comment: Yeah, I bet there probably is a good way to combine our methods into a hybrid approach that's smaller and faster. First thing that comes to mind is replacing the `removeRedundant()` method in my code with some of your regex magic. I might give that a try when I get home this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up implementing a completely non-regex, recursive approach to the problem. The `cleanupEqn()` function essentially splits each string by operators (top level parentheses are grouped as a single operand), recursively operates on each sub part, then does another run through on the way back up the function call chain.

[Comparing this with funkwurm's regex solution in jsperf](http://jsperf.com/testingeqnstringprocessing/3) shows it is significantly faster (at least in my personal chrome and firefox browsers).

It hasn't been thoroughly tested yet, and I'm sure there could be improvements made so I welcome any feedback.

Stealing funkwurm's snippet display to show my solution:

```js
var sEq = "(0+(0/0.5+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*cos(k)+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*(-sin(k))+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*0)*x+(0+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*sin(k)+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*cos(k)+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*0)*y+(0+(0+1*cos(p)+0*0+0*sin(p))*0+(0+1*0+0*1+0*0)*0+(0+1*(-sin(p))/0.5+0*0+0*cos(p))*1)*z)";

var operators = ['+','-','*','/'];
var level = 0;

var result = cleanupEqn(sEq);

document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = result;

function cleanupEqn(eqn){
    var parts = removeRedundant(splitByParen(eqn));
    level++;
    document.getElementById('output').value += 'Level ' + level + ': Processing ' + eqn + '\n';
    for(var i=0; i < parts.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('parts').value += parts[i] + '\n';
        if(parts[i].charAt(0) === '('){
            // Clean up the expression inside the parentheses
            var tmp = cleanupEqn(parts[i].substring(1,parts[i].length-1));

            // If it was reduced to a zero, don't add the parentheses back
            if(tmp === '0'){
                parts[i] = '0';
            }
            else {
                parts[i] = '(' + tmp + ')';
            }
        }
    }
    // Finally, remove redundancies again, since some might have bubbled up.
    removeRedundant(parts);
    
    document.getElementById('output').value += 'Level ' + level + ': Completed ' + eqn + '\n' + JSON.stringify(parts, null, '\t') + '\n';
    level--;
    // Join it all into a string and return
    return parts.join('');
}

function splitByParen(str){
    var out = [];
    var exprStart = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var t = str.charAt(i);
        if(str.charAt(i) === '('){
            if(i > exprStart && count === 0){
                out.push(str.substring(exprStart, i));
                exprStart = i;
            }
            count++;
        }
        else if(str.charAt(i) === ')'){
            count--;
            if(count === 0){
                out.push(str.substring(exprStart, i+1));
                exprStart = i+1;
            }
        }
        else if(count === 0 && operators.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) > -1){
            if(i > exprStart){
                out.push(str.substring(exprStart, i));
            }
            out.push(str.charAt(i));
            exprStart = i+1;
        }
    }
    
    // Add the last part
    if(i > exprStart){
        out.push(str.substring(exprStart, i));
    }
    return out;
}

function removeRedundant(parts) {
    for(var i=0; i < parts.length; i++){
        if(parts[i] === '0'){
            if(i === 0){
                switch(parts[i+1]){
                    case '*':
                    case '/':
                        if(parts[i+1] === '*' || parts[i+1] === '/'){
                            parts.splice(i, 3, '0');
                        }
                        else {
                            parts.splice(i, 2);
                        }
                        i--;
                        break;
                    case '+':
                        parts.splice(i, 2);
                        i--;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        parts.splice(i, 1);
                        i--;
                }
            }
            else {
                switch(parts[i-1]){
                    case '*':
                        if(parts[i+1] === '*' || parts[i+1] === '/'){
                            // Check if the prior portion is part of a function call
                            if(i > 2 && operators.indexOf(parts[i-3]) < 0){
                                // Check if the next portion is part of a function call (or undefined)
                                if(i+3 < parts.length && operators.indexOf(parts[i+3]) < 0){
                                    parts.splice(i-3, 6, '0');
                                    i -= 4;
                                }
                                else {
                                    parts.splice(i-3, 5, '0');
                                    i -= 4;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                parts.splice(i-2, 4, '0');
                                i -= 3;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            parts.splice(i-2, 3, '0');
                            i -= 3;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '+':
                    case '-':
                        if(parts[i+1] === '*' || parts[i+1] === '/'){
                            // Check if the next portion is part of a function call (or undefined)
                            if(i+3 < parts.length && operators.indexOf(parts[i+3]) < 0){
                                parts.splice(i, 4, '0');
                            }
                            else {
                                parts.splice(i, 3, '0');
                            }
                            i--;
                        }
                        else if(parts[i+1] === '+'){
                            parts.splice(i-1, 2);
                            i -= 2;
                        }
                        else {
                            parts.splice(i-1, 2);
                            i -= 2;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(parts[i] === '1'){
            if(i === 0){
                switch(parts[i+1]){
                    case '*':
                        parts.splice(i, 2);
                        i--;
                        break;
                    case '+':
                    case '-':
                        if(parts[i+1] === '*'){
                            parts.splice(i, 2);
                            i--;
                        }
                }
            }
            switch(parts[i-1]){
                case '*':
                case '/':
                    if(parts[i+1] !== '/'){
                        parts.splice(i-1, 2);
                        i -= 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case '+':
                case '-':
                    if(parts[i+1] === '*'){
                        parts.splice(i, 2);
                        i--;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return parts;
}
```

```html
<h3>Parts isolated:</h3>
<textarea id="parts" rows="10" style="width:100%" wrap="off"></textarea>
<h3>Steps that simplified the equation:</h3>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" style="width:100%" wrap="off"></textarea>
<h3>Solution:</h3>
<pre id="solution"></pre>
<script src="new.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, when I remove the part from my code that displays the steps in between, you're about 4x faster. Not as drastic as first but still significant. (My displaying code iterates through every step with every step so that's a exponential growth in the steps). In my experience recursion gets slow often, but not here evidently. I do wonder whether you have code redundant looking at parts like the `else { part.slice(); }} else { part.slice() } etc.` in `removeRedundant()`, stuff like that hints towards a limit in how many nested parentheses deep your code can deal with. But I could be wrong there.

Comment: All good points. I think one of the main performance gains I get with my method is it starts at the top level, so if there is a large expression multiplied with zero, like `(sin(x)*3+2*x+6y+cos(z)*12-8)*0` my code is able to remove it all at once without having to spend the time parsing it. The `Array.splice()` method could definitely get slow with large arrays, but I think as equations grow they tend to split things off into parentheses so I don't think the arrays will typically get too large.